# How to flatten List[Any]?

Tags: scala

In Scala, how can you flatten this:

```
List(1, List(2, 3), 4, List(5, 6, 7))
```

into this

```
List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
```

?

Comment: If you can avoid ending up with a `List[Any]` in the first place your life will be a lot better.

Comment: First convert it into a sane data type, then use the regular `flatten` method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A general solution from [scala99 problems](http://aperiodic.net/phil/scala/s-99/p07.scala)

```
def flatten(ls: List[Any]): List[Any] = ls flatMap {
case ms: List[_] => flatten(ms)
case e => List(e)
}                                               //> flatten: (ls: List[Any])List[Any]

flatten(List(1, List(2,3), 4, List(5,6,7)))     //> res0: List[Any] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you must deal with `Any`, you can do so by pattern matching at runtime:

```
def flatten(l: List[_]): List[Any] = l flatMap {
  case m: List[_] => flatten(m)
  case e => List(e)
}
```

But as @Erik says, it would be better to keep track of the type information all the way through, so that you can ensure you are handling all the cases correctly. For a more general version of Erik's solution, you can use shapeless: https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/shapeless/examples/flatten.scala (that example uses tuples, but the same thing works the same way with `HList`s)

Answer (score -2):

You should instead use a list of `Either[Int, List[Int]]`:

```
val xs: List[Either[Int, List[Int]]] = List(Left(1), Left(2), Right(List(1, 2, 3)), Left(7))
val xs1 = xs.flatMap {
  case Left(i)   => List(i)
  case Right(is) => is
}
```

On the other hand, you might be able to solve the problem by not generating such heterogenous list in the first place.

**Optional:**

With Scalaz's `\/`, replace `Either[Int, List[Int]]` with `Int \/ List[Int]`.

```
val xs: List[Int \/ List[Int]] = ...

val xs1 = xs.map {
  case -\/(i)  => ...
  case \/-(is) => ...
}
```

Comment: Downvotes don't require comments. Mine was that bringing Scalaz required changing the type of the input list and we've got two problems :(

Comment: The Scalaz bit was optional!