# Flatten list of any in scala

Tags: scala

I have

```
val a = List(1, List(2,3), 4)
```

I want to convert that list of any to `List[Int]`. How can I do this?

Expected answer is:

```
List(1,2,3,4)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to flatten List\[Any\]?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27679741/how-to-flatten-listany)

Comment: I don't think so since Mahek wants to obtain a `List[Int]` from a `List[Any]`. That question, instead, asks how to obtain a `List[Any]` from a `List[Any]`

Comment: Converting a `List[Any]` to any type, e.g. `List[Int]` is a code smell. What are you trying to do? If you don't have an `Int` in this `List[Any]`, what behavior do you expect?

Comment: @KevinMeredith I am checking only one condition `IF` and I am not using `ELSE` that's why I am getting 'List[Any]`

Comment: I don't understand, Mahek. Care to post another SO question?

Comment: @KevinMeredith Sorry for delay. I have two list A and B.
I am doing `A . map(x => B . map ( y => if ( sum ( x , y ) == true )  ( x , y ) )`
Using that I am getting `List[Any]` and now I want to convert it to `List[Int]`
Its same as two nested `for` loops in c and you want to use only one condition. `sum` is some function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you're doing something wrong in your overall code. This is not how you're supposed to work with the type system. Anyway:

```
val a = List(1, List(2,3), 4)

a.flatMap({
  case i: Int => List(i)
  case l: List[Int] => l
})
```

Comment: Thank you.. I m beginner in this language so m not that much good with type system. I am trying to learn it . Anyways thanks a lot :)

Comment: @MahekShah why do you have a `List[Any]`? Always try to avoid `Any`.

Comment: Some times I am using only one condition in map statement that's why m getting List of any..
But just now come to know first filter on that condition and then apply map function that way I can avoid `Any` type

Comment: And also if I want to check only `IF` condition like if(list.filter(condition).length>0) then do something without `else` part, at that time I am getting list of `Any`. Any way to prevent this?

Comment: @Reactormonk `case l: List[Int] => l` does not work because of type erasure.

Comment: @MahekShah so please post your initial problem as a question. If you get `Any`, your approach is incorrect.

Comment: @lambdista yeah, that's a valid critique.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot use:

```
a.flatMap({
  case i: Int => List(i)
  case l: List[Int] => l
})
```

The `case l: List[Int]` part does not work because of type erasure. As a matter of fact:

```
scala> val a = List(1, List("a"), 3)
a: List[Any] = List(1, List(a), 3)

scala> a.flatMap {
     |   case i: Int => List(i)
     |   case l: List[Int] => l
     | }
<console>:11: warning: non-variable type argument Int in type pattern List[Int] (the underlying of List[Int]) is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
          case l: List[Int] => l
                  ^
res2: List[Int] = List(1, a, 3)

scala> res2(1) // boom!
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer 
at scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.unboxToInt(BoxesRunTime.java:105)
  ... 33 elided
```

In these cases you may want to consider using the `Typeable` type class you get with [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) for type safe casts. E.g.:

```
scala> import shapeless.syntax.typeable._
import shapeless.syntax.typeable._

scala> val as = a.flatMap {
     |   case x: Int => List(x)
     |   case xs => xs.cast[List[Int]].getOrElse(List())
     | }
as: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)

scala> val b = List(1, 2, List("a", "b"), 3)
b: List[Any] = List(1, 2, List(a, b), 3)

scala> val bs = b.flatMap {
     |   case x: Int => List(x)
     |   case xs => xs.cast[List[Int]].getOrElse(List())
     | }
bs: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

As you can the `cast[T]` method, added to every type by shapeless through `implicits`, returns an `Option[T]` whose value is `None` if the cast fails, `Some` if it's successful.

Of course you can decide to fail in case the content of your very first list isn't either an `Int` or a `List[Int]`. In my example I decided just to ignore other types and still produce a `List[Int]`.